# What are some good attacking games from the black side of the Queen's Gambit Declined (Exchange variation)?

Tags: opening, strategy, queens-gambit-declined

I read both of the answers to [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/what-are-blacks-possible-plans-in-the-exchange-variation-of-the-queens-gambit), and although one answer hints that black can launch a kingside attack in the Exchange variation, it offers no games demonstrating such a kingside attack.

What are some games demonstrating a kingside attack from the black side of the Queen's Gambit Declined (Exchange variation)?

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion :

[Boensch-Vaganian, 1983](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1145663)

Bring the Bishop to d6, move the kingside pawns forward, try to dominate square e4.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a very well known game, but [Bobotsov-Petrosian](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1106817) is definitely highly instructive how to play the Exchange variation of the QGD:

- First, black exchanges a couple of minor pieces, as he lacks space
- By putting a knight on d6, black stops white's play on the queen side
- Then, black starts a king side attack

**Edit:** A similar approach can be found in the game [Portisch-Kasparov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1070466), another very instructive game from black's point of view.

Comment: That game was painful to watch, white did a lot of wrong things, especially allowing Bf5 and even trading off his ls bishop. Not to mention he never developed a plan and shuffled his pieces around on the kingside before resigning. That was ugly.

Comment: Sure, but that's often the case for instructive games... :-D. Btw, apparently, Bobotsov was actually a strong player (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milko_Bobotsov) and his best tournament result is quite impressive (see http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=79435).